# VBA Powerpoint - find HIGHLIGHTED text in shape, then ADD a new text box with ANIMATION effect

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have this Powerpoint file. Here the link:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JaRrBDOEKkCnxeGHrynwdmhPtaOZ8Y4f

I have turned a MS Word file into Powerpoint file using the instruction in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7oao6EzF08U

[after conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fo9OI.png)

I want to **unhighlight** the text, then add a new text box (Red shape fill and Send behind text) with **ANIMATION effect**, put it in the position of the unhighlighted text like in the pictures.

[unhighlight text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yX7BR.png)

[add new text box with animation effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yqlbu.png)

Therefore, I can show the correct answer to my students when teaching using PPT.

I have about 100 slides like this but I don't have enough time to do it all manually.

Unfortunately, MS Powerpoint doesn't have Macro Recorder like in MS Word and I also don't know much about VBA code.

Is there any way to use VBA code to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Although a good question, it is better to upload an image directly into the question, since link addresses  may change over time.

Comment: rainer - I did put the image in the Image icon, but It always turns into the link. I can't upload it directly into the question. Is it because of my new account?

Comment: does anyone can help me with this?